# Getting GUID from mongodb insert statement using java API

Tags: java, mongodb

I am creating a document in mongodb using something like this:

```
DBCollection coll =<code to get collection>;
WriteResult res = coll.insert(obj, new WriteConcern());
```

I then want the GUID of the newly inserted thing.  Doing a search for obj would work, but that would be not efficient at all.

Comment: You can try  res.getField("_id")

Comment: I tried that but it was null.

Comment: The only thing that came back in res was this document: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "connectionId" : 480 , "n" : 0 , "syncMillis" : 0 , "writtenTo" :  null  , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}

Comment: ObjectId id = (ObjectId)obj.get( "_id" );

Comment: obj doesn't have a guid.  They get their guid from the database when they get inserted.  The problem is I don't have a really good way to find what the GUID it got assigned was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the write concern correctly, it is better to use the  static ones defined in the class. After an insert the document _id can be found in the object you just inserted:

```
DBCollection coll =<code to get collection>;
DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("foo",42);
coll.insert(obj, WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);
System.out.println("New _id:" + obj.get("_id");
```

I rarely use the WriteResult returned by inserts for anything.